# next-auth credential provider session/token

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth

Short story, I'm trying to implement [next-auth's credentials provider](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials), and am not getting a session on the front end.

If I put

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    setValidating(localStorage.getItem('idapEmailValidating') || false);
    console.log('in effect we have a session of');
    console.log(session);

  if (status === 'loading') {
    return <Text>Loading ...</Text>
  }
  ...
```

anywhere, then I get this in the console:

```
[Log] in effect we have a session of
[Log] undefined
[Log] in effect we have a session of
[Log] null
```

and it never turns to not `null`.

On the backend, authentication seems to be working, because I put `console.log` in all of the events, and the signIn event is being hit:

```
// output of console.log:
In signIn event {
  user: { email: 'tim@jones.com', newsletter: true, exclusive: null },
  account: {
    providerAccountId: undefined,
    type: 'credentials',
    provider: 'credentials'
  }
}
```

And the [docs for the signIn event](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events#signin) say, "Sent on a successful sign in." So ... all should be good?

How do I get a session on the front end when using credential provider?

After much consternation (and googling), I found [this discussion on Github](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4144), which indicates, "Apparently when using credentials you **need** to manually encode/decode your JWT."

More than a year after that discussion, there's no such mention in the next-auth docs, nor is it done in any of the credential-provider examples; nevertheless, maybe it's true. So I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73197592/11020164) (which was answering a different question) that indicates how to just use the native next-auth code to issue a token with next-auth v4, and adapted it to this in `authOptions`:

```
jwt: {
    encode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {
        console.log('token received in jwt');
        console.log(token);
        return encode(token, secret, maxAge);
    },
    decode: async ( secret, token ) => {
        return decode(token, secret);
    },
},
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
error - Error [TypeError]: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string
```

And I suspect the issue there is that the token isn't coming in with `ikm`, or any of the other normal next-auth token parameters. The `console.log` from that last bit says

```
token received in jwt
{
  name: undefined,
  email: 'bob@smith.com',
  picture: undefined,
  sub: undefined,
  exclusive: null,
  newsletter: true
}
```

What am I doing wrong here to get the session on the front end? I'm not even sure this "add a jwt section to authOptions" is going in the right direction.

More details below.

---

The actual use case is to just do a modified version of the email provider (I want to intercept the flow and, e.g., send different verification emails depending on how/where the user signed in; and do some role based stuff — I fiddled with the email provider for about a week before deciding it was impossible and switching to the credentials provider).

I *think* I have the authentication function working properly.

I have a form that does

```
const onSubmit = async ({values, validator = () => null, status}) => {
    ...

    // else sign-in with email, then subscribe
    const res = await signIn('credentials', {
        email: values.email,
        form: 'newsletter',
        redirect: false
    });

    if (res?.error) {
        if (res.error === 'verifying') {
            localStorage.setItem('idapEmailValidating', true);
            validator(true);
        }
    } else {
        validator(true);
        // set this in local storage, as the session doesn't actually
        // get created until after the email has been validated
        localStorage.setItem('idapEmailValidating', 'true');
    }

    await fetch('/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
          'Content-Type': 'applcation/json',
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values)
    })
}
```

That works fine, enters stuff in the database, and sends an email, which links back to the login page, with, e.g.,

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/login?token=d536dce8f6cad7ff34615edbfea7c022b3e303cb178460a17123ab4115fc05be&email=bob%40smith.com
```

NB, that token is an email validation token, not the actual auth token. The signin page then grabs those query params and signs in with them:

```
// pages/auth/login.js
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

function Signin({ layout }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { status } = useSession();

  if (status === 'authenticated') {
    router.push('/');
  }

  // check if we're doing the verification step
  const { token, email } = router.query;

  if (token && email) {
    const res = signIn('credentials', {}, { token: token, email: email });
  }
  ...
```

So, I'm using the native signIn function from next-auth, and [the docs indicate](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages#credentials-sign-in) that by doing that I don't need to worry about any csrf stuff, and it should kind of Just Work.

On the backend, if it comes through this mechanism, I just return the `user` object from the `authenticate` callback:

```
const authOptions = {
    secret: requireEnvVariable('NEXTAUTH_SECRET'),
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
    pages: {
        signIn: '/auth/login',
        signOut: '/auth/signout',
        error: '/auth/error',
        verifyRequest: '/auth/verify-request',
        newUser: '/auth/new-user'
    },
    session: {
        // Since we're using Prisma, we force a JWT session by explicitly defining `"jwt"`.
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            name: 'Email Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email', placeholder: 'bob@example.com' },
                form: { }
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const { token, email } = req?.query;

                if ( token && email ) {
                    try {
                        // do backend stuff to make sure the token is valid, etc...

                        return user;
                    } catch (error) {
                        return Promise.reject(new Error(error));
                    }
                }
                // ... other auth scenarios
    cookies: cookies,
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ user, token, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
            console.log('In JWT callback');
            if (user) {
                token.exclusive = user.exclusive;
                token.newsletter = user.newsletter;
            }    

            return token;
        },
        session({ session, token, user }) {
            console.log('in session callback')
            /* update the sessions.user based on the token object */
            if (token && session.user) {
                session.user.exclusive = token.exclusive;
                session.user.newsletter = token.newsletter;
            } else if (user && session.user) {
                session.user.exclusive = user.exclusive;
                session.user.newsletter = user.newsletter;
            }
            return session;
        },
        signIn() {
            console.log('in signin callback');
            return true;
        },
        redirect({url, baseUrl}) {
            console.log('in redirect callback');
            console.log(url);
            console.log(baseUrl);
            return baseUrl;
        }
    },
    jwt: {
        encode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {
            console.log('token received in jwt');
            console.log(token);
            return encode(token, secret, maxAge);
        },
        decode: async ({ secret, token }) => {
            return decode(token, secret);
        },
    },
    events: {
        async signIn(message) { '/* on successful sign in */' 
        console.log('In signIn event', message)
    },
        async signOut(message) { /* on signout */ 
        console.log('In signOut event', message)
    },
        async createUser(message) { /* user created */ 
        console.log('In createUser event', message)
    },
        async updateUser(message) { /* user updated - e.g. their email was verified */ 
        console.log('In updateUser event', message)
    },
        async linkAccount(message) { /* account (e.g. Twitter) linked to a user */ 
        console.log('In linkAccount event', message)
    },
        async session(message) { /* session is active */ 
        console.log('In session event', message)
    },
      }
}
```

As you can see, I've put logging events pretty much everywhere to see what it's doing, and this is what it does:

```
in redirect callback
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000
in redirect callback
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000
in redirect callback
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000
in redirect callback
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000
in redirect callback
http://localhost:3000/auth/login?token=402027d3e7bcd34c9a04c1a35ca36282e780578a0ff4d75b8b233bd10f9b8c23&email=bob%40smith.com
http://localhost:3000
In authentication callback
[Object: null prototype] {
  csrfToken: '8f35c186a03abaa370d2db737846acb0c74955ce6f6b2b52f8f54c166a907407',
  callbackUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login?token=402027d3e7bcd34c9a04c1a35ca36282e780578a0ff4d75b8b233bd10f9b8c23&email=bob%40smith.com',
  json: 'true'
}
{
  token: '402027d3e7bcd34c9a04c1a35ca36282e780578a0ff4d75b8b233bd10f9b8c23',
  email: 'bob@smith.com'
}
got token & email
in signin callback
In JWT callback
token received in jwt
{
  name: undefined,
  email: 'bob@smith.com',
  picture: undefined,
  sub: undefined,
  exclusive: null,
  newsletter: true
}
error - Error [TypeError]: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string
```

Comment: did you wrap your app with `SessionProvider`

Comment: yes, thusly: `function App({
    Component,
    pageProps: { session, ...pageProps }
  }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
export default App;`

Comment: you are not using next.js13 app directory,right?

Comment: Nope. This is the "old" /pages style, but Next 13.3.0 (next-auth 4.22.0).